# Split multiple page PDF document in smaller documents BASED ON FIELD CONTENT (invoice number)

Tags: php, pdf, split

There are a lot of similar questions, but none with the variation that I have.

I have multiple PDF documents that vary in page numbers.
Each PDF contains a number of Invoices, they also vary in page number.

I don't have a constant number of pages per invoice or number of invoices per initial PDF documents.

I need to split these PDF documents in smaller ones based on the Invoice number.

I prefer to use PHP, but any sugestion will do.
Thank you.

Comment: How to recognize the start of the next invoice?

Comment: The field with the invoice number changes, and there also is a field that prints "page X out of Y".

Comment: Do you mean PDF Acroform form fields? Or are those XFA form fields? Or something else altogether?

Comment: I mean strings of text that exist in a specific location on the page...

Comment: So your task involves text extraction from the document (the invoice number). I hope you are aware that text extraction from PDFs can be a fickle process and, therefore, have already checked whether that is uniformly possible in case of your documents?

Comment: Actually, I need to split a document based on that invoice number in smaller PDF documents.The PDF documents are generated, so the field with the invoice number is always in the same spot.